# Create new class instances by extracting information from a list

Tags: c#

*Note that this code uses C#7 functionality like <strike>local methods and</strike> `ValueTuple`*

I am programming an HMI for an industrial machine. Part of the HMI's task is to read the machine settings and present them in better human understandable concepts. In this case a `Material` and its corresponding `MaterialWebfeedSettings`.

In the following method I extract information from a `List` of `MachineSetting` which contains the information needed to create a `Material` instance and `MaterialWebfeedSettings` instances for each `WebfeedModule` on the machine.

The `Dictionary<ModuleTypes, List<MachineProperty>> WebfeedModuleSettingProperties` contains a `List` of `MachineProperty` for each possible `ModuleTypes` that is aso a `WebfeedModule`.

`List<(ModuleTypes type, Int32 sequenceNumber)> WebfeedModules` contains all the WebfeedModules on the machine.

**My main concern with this method is readability and coding style**, and performance to a lesser extend.

```
private static List<(ModuleTypes type, Int32 sequenceNumber)> WebfeedModules;

private static Dictionary<ModuleTypes, List<MachineProperty>> WebfeedModuleSettingProperties;

private static (Material, List<MaterialWebfeedSettings>) ExtractMaterial(List<MachineSetting> machineSettings)
    {
        Func<MachineSetting, Boolean> IsWebThickness = s => s.MachinePropertyID == MachineProperties.MainCtrl_rWebThicknessSetting;
        Func<MachineSetting, Boolean> IsWebStretch = s => s.MachinePropertyID == MachineProperties.MainCtrl_rWebStretchSetting;
        Func<MachineSetting, Boolean> IsTaperStartTens = s => s.MachinePropertyID == MachineProperties.Rewind_rTaperStartTens;
        Func<MachineSetting, Boolean> IsMinStopDiameter = s => s.MachinePropertyID == MachineProperties.Unwind_rMinStopDiameter;

        Single thickness = Single.Parse(machineSettings.First(IsWebThickness).ValueEnd);
        Single stretch = Single.Parse(machineSettings.First(IsWebStretch).ValueEnd);
        Single windingTension = Single.Parse(machineSettings.First(IsTaperStartTens).ValueEnd);
        Single minStopDiameter = Single.Parse(machineSettings.First(IsMinStopDiameter).ValueEnd);

        Material material = new Material("", thickness, stretch, true, windingTension, minStopDiameter);

        List<MaterialWebfeedSettings> settings = new List<MaterialWebfeedSettings>();

        foreach ((ModuleTypes type, Int32 sequenceNumber) module in WebfeedModules)
        {
            Func<MachineSetting, Boolean> IsWebtension = s => s.MachinePropertyID == WebfeedModuleSettingProperties[module.type][Webtension].ID;
            Func<MachineSetting, Boolean> IsWebtensionControl = s => s.MachinePropertyID == WebfeedModuleSettingProperties[module.type][WebtensionControl].ID;
            Func<MachineSetting, Boolean> IsSpeedOffset = s => s.MachinePropertyID == WebfeedModuleSettingProperties[module.type][SpeedOffset].ID;

            String settingWebtensionValue = machineSettings.FirstOrDefault(IsWebtension)?.ValueEnd;
            String settingWebTensionControlValue = machineSettings.FirstOrDefault(IsWebtensionControl)?.ValueEnd;
            String settingSpeedOffsetValue = machineSettings.FirstOrDefault(IsSpeedOffset)?.ValueEnd;

            String defaultWebtensionValue = WebfeedModuleSettingProperties[module.type][Webtension].DefaultRecipeValue;
            String defaultWebtensionControlValue = WebfeedModuleSettingProperties[module.type][WebtensionControl].DefaultRecipeValue;
            String defaultSpeedOffsetValue = WebfeedModuleSettingProperties[module.type][SpeedOffset].DefaultRecipeValue;

            Int32 webTension = Int32.TryParse(settingWebtensionValue, out Int32 webTensionValue) ? webTensionValue : Int32.Parse(defaultWebtensionValue);
            Boolean closedLoop = Boolean.TryParse(settingWebTensionControlValue, out Boolean webTensionControlValue) ? webTensionControlValue : Boolean.Parse(defaultWebtensionControlValue);
            Single speedOffset = Single.TryParse(settingSpeedOffsetValue, out Single speedOffsetValue) ? speedOffsetValue : Single.Parse(defaultSpeedOffsetValue);

            settings.Add(new MaterialWebfeedSettings(material, (WebFeedModule)(Int32)module.type, module.sequenceNumber, webTension, closedLoop, speedOffset));
        }

        return (material, settings);
    }
```

Comment: Well, you're using value tuple but there are no local functions, lambdas like `IsWebThickness` were already possible in C# 6.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Func<MachineSetting, Boolean> IsWebThickness = s => s.MachinePropertyID == MachineProperties.MainCtrl_rWebThicknessSetting;
> ```

This is not a local function, it's a variable of `Func` type and as such it should be *camelCase* and not *PascalCase*. This is a local fuction:

```
bool IsWebThickness(MachineSetting s) => s.MachinePropertyID == MachineProperties.MainCtrl_rWebThicknessSetting;
```

It's as if you placed a normal method inside another method but without the access modifier.